# CSS Flexbox in Adobe AIR?

Tags: css, air, adobe

Does Adobe AIR Support the css flexbox properties and how do I declare it in my css file (-webkit-...?)?

And is there any list or collection of which css properties are supported by AIR or any browser?

Update#1 
As alex said it should work. So is something wrong with my css?

```
.header
{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grainsboro;
    border-bottom: rgb(200,200,200) 1px solid;
    color: rgb(45,45,45);
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper
{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-align-self: stretch;
    color: grey;
    background-color: steelblue;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body
{
    display:  -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
    background-color: green;
}
```

This setup works at least in chrome without any problems.

Update#2

After long research I made it working. I tried the old flexbox properties ( e.g. display: -webkit-box) and it workz now. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be supported and i won't copy code from another site, just use the official adobe developer articles, they will help you :

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/working-with-flexbox-the-new-spec.html

Comment: Thanks alex. Already saw this page hundred times but never recognized that's about AIR. Updated the question.